Importing yfinance library does not let me print anything
I've been working on a stock screener using python and when I tried working on it again after taking a break, my program stopped printing things out and honestly, it's like it is skipping the whole program. Even running something easy like printing one line does not work when importing yfinance. This is only specific to this library, others like datetime, pandas, and requests don't do anything to it. Anyone have any suggestions?
Trying something like this will not print anything:
import yfinance

print(2)

However, this will print 4:
print(4)

import yfinance

print(2)


Hm. Have you tried any other method of getting output out of your program? My thought is that either 1) yfinance is specifically nuking print somehow, or 2) it's halting operation of your code somehow. Trying to, say, write to a file, or open a tkinter window (after the import, of course), could help eliminate one of those.
